# Is it possible to simplify the product $\prod_{i=1}^n (9i^2 - 1)$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, factorial, gamma-function, products

Is is possible to reduce this product to something that only relates (max.) on the calculation of "$\Gamma(x)$ constants (e.g. $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$)" and (single) factorials.

I've started with Mathematicas calculated identity:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (9i^2 - 1) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{2}{3} + n) \Gamma(\frac{4}{3} + n)}{2 π} * 3^{\frac{3}{2} + 2 n}$$

I can [simplify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments) $\Gamma(\frac{4}{3} + n) = \Gamma(\frac{1}{3} + (n+1))$ [to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments) $$ = \Gamma(\frac{1}{3}) * \frac{(3(n+1) - 2)!!!}{3^{n+1}} = \Gamma(\frac{1}{3}) * \frac{(3n + 1)!!!}{3^{n+1}}$$

Is it now possible to reduce $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3}) * \frac{(3n + 1)!!!}{3^{n+1}}$ and $\Gamma(\frac{2}{3} + n)$ to a 'representation' that is only with n-independent Gamma function-values and single factorials (not third)?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: product of (9i^2 - 1), thank you - I "fixed" this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm being dense, we have
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^n (9i^2-1) &= \prod_{i=1}^n [(3i-1)(3i+1)] = [2\cdot 4]\cdot[5\cdot 7] \cdots [(3n-1)(3n+1)] \\
&=\frac{(3n+1)!}{3\cdot 6 \cdots 3n} = \frac{(3n+1)!}{3^n n!}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{i=1}^n(3i-1)(3i+1)=\frac{(3n+1)!}{\prod_{i=1}^n 3i}=\frac{(3n+1)!}{n!3^n}.$$